# Can I change the hover cursor of a datapoint in a AnyChart Column chart?

Tags: anychart

I have a AnyChart column chart in which the dataitems when clicked on will redirect to another page in my solution.
Is it possible to set the hover cursor for these dataitems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a hoverCursor() effect for individual columns, you could use listen() method to create a listener for a “pointMousOver” event and do it again for a “pointMousOut”.

```
// create an event listener for the pointMouseOut event
chart.listen("pointMouseOver", function(e){
    // change the cursor style
    document.body.style.cursor = "pointer";
});
  
// create an event listener for the pointMouseOut event
chart.listen("pointMouseOut", function(e){
    // set the default cursor style
    document.body.style.cursor = "auto";
});
```

Shown in this sample: https://playground.anychart.com/mVLAJ3Pm/2